# bash grep text within squared brackets

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I try to grep a text from a log file on a linux bash.The text is within two square brackets.

e.g. in:

```
32432423 jkhkjh [234] hkjh32 2342342
```

I am searching `234`.

usually that should find it

```
 \[(.*?)\]
```

but not with

```
|grep \[(.*?)\]
```

what is the correct way to do the regular expression search with grep

Comment: You don't need the parentheses. Or the question-mark.

Comment: you mean like that  |grep \\[.*\\] ? did not work for me on a red hat linux

Comment: When I tried `echo "32432423 jkhkjh [234] hkjh32 2342342" | grep '\[.*\]'` it seemed to work fine on my Debian system. It matched the `[234]` part.

Comment: You need to post the exact command which you used, not just the regex pattern.

Comment: Note that the question mark (non-greedy search) is not enabled for simple regular expressions. You need at least extended regex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can look for an opening bracket and clear with the `\K` escape sequence. Then, match up to the closing bracket:

```
$ grep -Po '\[\K[^]]*' <<< "32432423 jkhkjh [234] hkjh32 2342342"
234
```

Note you can omit the `-P` (Perl extended regexp) by saying:

```
$ grep -o '\[.*]' <<< "32432423 jkhkjh [234] hkjh32 2342342"
[234]
```

However, as you see, this prints the brackets also. That's why it is useful to have `-P` to perform a look-behind and look-after.

You also mention `?` in your regexp. Well, as you already know, `*?` is to have a regex match behave in a non-greedy way. Let's see an example:

```
$ grep -Po '\[.*?]' <<< "32432423 jkhkjh [23]4] hkjh32 2342342"
[23]
$ grep -Po '\[.*]' <<< "32432423 jkhkjh [23]4] hkjh32 2342342"
[23]4]
```

With `.*?`, in `[23]4]` it matches `[23]`. With just `.*`, it matches up to the last `]` hence getting `[23]4]`. This behaviour just works with the `-P` option.

Answer (score 7):

To grep all values between square brackets *including* the brackets you may use a POSIX BRE based `grep` command like

```
grep -o '\[[^][]*]' file
```

**...and BONUS solutions of the same kind:**

```
grep -o '<[^<>]*>' file # Extracting all strings between angle brackets
grep -o '([^()]*)' file # Extracting all strings between parentheses
grep -o '{[^{}]*}' file # Extracting all strings between curly braces
grep -o '"[^"]*"'  file # Extracting all strings between double quotes
grep -o "'[^']*'"  file # Extracting all strings between single quotes
```

See the [online `grep` demo](https://ideone.com/rYbi8t). The `-o` option makes `grep` output matched substrings only, not whole lines, and the `\[[^][]*]` pattern matches a `[`, then 0 or more occurrences of any chars but `[` and `]` (see the negated `[^][]*` bracket expression), and then a `]`.

If you need to get the value inside square brackets *excluding* the square brackets, you can use a PCRE regex based `grep` commands like

```
grep -oP '\[\K[^][]*(?=])' file
```

See [another online demo](https://ideone.com/G60Hvz)

The `\[\K[^][]*(?=])` pattern matches

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `\K` - a match reset operator that discards the text matched so far from the match memory buffer
- `[^][]*` - 0 or more chars other than `]` and `[`
- `(?=])` - a positive lookahead that requires a `]` char immediately to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer `\\[[^]]*]` (that's: `\\[ [ ^] ]* ]`, ie. *anything-but-right-square-brackets in square brackets*) over `\\[.*]` because of greediness:

```
$ grep -o \\[.*] <<<"[this] and that too]"
[this] and that too]
```

vs.

```
$ grep -o \\[[^]]*] <<<"[this] and that too]"
[this]
```

Then again `grep` is not the tool for everything (it was `g/re/p` after all). If you just want what's inside the square brackets, I'd use `sed` for that:

```
$ sed 's/.*\[\([^]]*\)].*/\1/' foo
234
```

ie. *replace-everything-with-what's-in-parenthesis...sies*.

Answer (score 0):

`[` has special meaning to both the shell *and* `grep`, so you need to quote it *twice*. The backslashes prevent `grep` from treating them as part of a bracket expression; quoting the entire thing prevents the shell from trying to expand the regular expression as a pattern before passing it to `grep`.

```
... | grep '\[(.*?)\]'
```

In your attempt, the shell stripped the backslashes after they were to force the shell to treat them literally, it was approximately to `... | grep '[(.*?)]'`.